# Automapper - How to map three entity to one with automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, typeconverter

I have 3 entity: `Obj1`, `Obj2`, `Obj3`

How to map 3 entity to one with automapper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This post](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx) describes how to map multiple objects into a single new object, using the following helper class:

```
public static class EntityMapper
{
    public static T Map<T>(params object[] sources) where T : class
    {
        if (!sources.Any())
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        var initialSource = sources[0];

        var mappingResult = Map<T>(initialSource);

        // Now map the remaining source objects
        if (sources.Count() > 1)
        {
            Map(mappingResult, sources.Skip(1).ToArray());
        }

        return mappingResult;
    }

    private static void Map(object destination, params object[] sources)
    {
        if (!sources.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var destinationType = destination.GetType();

        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            var sourceType = source.GetType();

            Mapper.Map(source, destination, sourceType, destinationType);
        }
    }

    private static T Map<T>(object source) where T : class
    {
        var destinationType = typeof(T)
        var sourceType = source.GetType();

        var mappingResult = Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);

        return mappingResult as T;
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
var personViewModel = EntityMapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person, address, comment);
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that it is needed to map them to `Obj0`. Basically you need to map them one by one.

```
Mapper.Map(Obj1, Obj0);
Mapper.Map(Obj2, Obj0);
Mapper.Map(Obj3, Obj0);
```

In more advanced scenarios you can compose you types into some `CompositeObj` and create mapping between `Obj0` and `CompositeObj`.